# Package.Json was not modified on Dependencies after I installed bootstrap using npm

Tags: angularjs, node.js, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, npm-install

What I did first when creating MVC.Core using Angular 4 was:

1. Install nodejs
2. Created MVC Core Project
3. I used CMD and changes dir to the project MVC Core
4. I used

> npm install @angular/cli --global

or

> used npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest

5. Then I install bootstrap using

> npm install boostrap --save

When checking my package.json still the same with NO Bootstrap was added and looks like this

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1"
  }
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved this using the command

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

What I did was to repeat the steps 1 to 3 and replaced the step 4 with it. Now, the dependencies was modified and was added the bootstrap dependencies.